# I got this error when using "apachectl -k restart" command in docker, http: php, please

Tags: docker

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message :)

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. It tells you that the server does not have an explicitly configured name and because of that it will use an IP-address instead. As Hernan said, you need to set ServerName globally, if you do not want to see this again.